# How I can deserialize my string into decimal property using JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here is the class

```
 public class ModelingData : BaseEquatable<ModelingData>
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(DecimalToStringConvertor))]
        public decimal? ActualValue { get; set; }

        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(ModelingData other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return Equals(other.ActualValue, ActualValue);
        }
    }
```

And I have created class

```
public class DecimalToStringConvertor : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            string javaScriptTicks = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(value)) ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;
            writer.WriteValue(javaScriptTicks);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (existingValue == null)
            {
                return 0M;
            }

            return Convert.ToDecimal(existingValue);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now when I am trying to deserialize it, It gives me always null in existingValue parameter of ReadJson Method. It is working fine for WriteJson.

How I can deserialize my string into decimal property using JsonConverter?

Comment: did you solve it? if yes, please answer your own question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reading the help topic at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm specifies that "Instructs the JsonSerializer to use the specified JsonConverter when serializing the member or class." So to me it seems that the JsonConverter attribute is not used for de-serializiation but only for serializing object.

If you try instead to pass a new instance of your class as a parameter to the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function such as:

```
ModelingData md = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelingData>(jsonData, new DecimalToStringConvertor());
```

I believe you should have more success.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer to accomplish you task.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
```

There are also a lot of libraries for  json serialization fro example service stack solution.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer has the Deserialize method as well.